# Need to change my printer driver and can't find the list

Tags: drivers, printing

I have a HP DeskJet 1112 which was working fine.  Then it suddenly stopped working -- would print only blank pages.  I checked HPLIP and it seemed to have been disturbed, so I re-installed that.  But it is still printing blank pages.

I recall now that when I first installed it, the recommended driver did print blank pages, and I found another driver on the list that worked correctly.  So I deleted the printer and clicked to add it again.

It was added, but I did not get the list of drivers so I could choose the one that works. How do I get that list and select the correct driver?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Rather than using the Ubuntu printer GUI, you might want access your printer install via CUPS. More on CUPS here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html

Comment: I'm in 14.04.  I used your serverguide link to look at CUPS.  It appears to be installed, but I don't think it's running.  I couldn't find the config file at all.  I tried restarting cups without success.  My terminal: betty@zareason-limbo5880:/$ sudo systemctl restart cups.service[sudo] password for betty: 
sudo: systemctl: command not found
any further advice?  should  I try to re-install CUPS?

Comment: If CUPS is running, you should be able to access from your web browser at http://localhost:631. From there, you can review your printers, reconfigure, etc.

Comment: Yes I SHOULD be able to, but I keep getting an unable to connect message, although I was able to get up on it in the past.  I found a way to stop and restart CUPS, but that didn't help anything.  I'm wondering if I should reinstall CUPS.  If I try to do that, will it automatically uninstall whatever version is there?

Comment: The link reference was for Ubuntu 16.04, and not 14.04. Systemd doesn't exist natively in 14.04, so the systemctl command won't work. Instead, to restart CUPS, use the command `sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart`.

Comment: yes, I was able to restart CUPS, but it didn't get localhost:631 running.  Do you think I should try to re-install it?

Comment: Before reinstalling, first try to reconfigure, using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure cups`. If that fails, then a reinstall of the CUPS packages is a good next step (`sudo apt-get --reinstall install cups`). However, that doesn't explain the root cause of the problem which is still unknown. In advance of a reinstall, you might want to first look to see if all the dependencies for the CUPS packages are correctly met using `sudo apt-cache depends cups`. This will tell you if you're missing dependencies, which might provide a clue as to why your CUPS system failed in the first place. Good luck!

Comment: Rich, all of the above did not help.   The version of CUPS I have put the cuspd.conf in binary so I can't edit it.  I checked for listeners and found cupsd.sock which is blank. Then I found a way (completely undocumented)  to get the GUI interface to give me a list of the ppd's, so I was able to re-install the printer and it is now working.    Thank you for your help.